# How to link multiple ports from a Expression to multiple groups of a Union

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I add an image in order to explain myself better.

I have 300 something ports in a expression. I have created the equivalent number of groups in a union. I want each port of this expression to go to a port/field of the Union. One to one relationship. It seems like powercenter is not able to do this with autolink, or at least I'm unable to find the proper way to do this. How could I work arround this issue? Because I've been told that is likely that in a few days it will be more than 700 ports, and the amount it takes to do by hand is quite insane. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it validates... union is for homogenous sources but you seem to be trying to pivot your data (in which case I'd suggest using another transformation i.e. a normalizer and Informatica will start behaving as expected)

Comment: That's my guess as well. @monkey_intern, can you please describe the purpose of your mapping? There might be a better way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: make a bunch of connections, save and export the file as xml, go to the lines when the connections are done, and replace that zone with as many rows as you need.

What I did specifically was to get the original rows, change the names as appropiate with the help of notepad++ and excel, and then go back to the original file and replace all of it. Check everything three times, and import the file back to powercenter.

I say possible solution because it's messy and dirty, but even though it may lead to mistakes I feel like the amount is vastly inferior and you have the versioning on your side, so just save before exporting. If someone with more experience could tell me it's thoughts about this, it would be a great opportunity to learn, just leaving this in case it goes unanswered